# AS3 ServerSocket / Socket dropping intermittently

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, networking, tcp

Making a game that uses an android tablet as a controller. Both the game and the controller being written in Flash / AS3. 
Mostly it is working well. However, on occasion, the controller will just stop sending data. The server is receiving messages they are just blank. 
I am using the accelerometer on the device to control the game, and send the 'angle' at 50ms intervals. Sometimes I can play through all three game levels 10 times with no issue. And then once in a while I'll be playing and the accel data is blank. 
Not sure what is happening... I'm not getting a disconnect or other error - the server keeps replying showing that the clientMessage handler is being called - it just shows blank data.

Comment: 50ms interval is pretty fast. Maybe your socket gets flooded with data. You need to be sure that both the client and the server are ready to send/receive those packages. Try to profile both sides - there is no common solution because there is no actual problem (as you said, most of the time it works). Nobody can help you magically :) Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229237/flash-xml-socket-choking

Comment: Thanks, I upped the interval to 120ms and it seems to be behaving much better.